# Is it really necessary the handshakng on an RS232 connection?

Tags: serial-port, communication, uart, handshaking

I'm building an electronic device that has to be prepared for RS232 connections, and I'd like to know if it's really necessary to make room for more than 3 pins (Tx, Rx, GND) on each port.

If I don't use the rest of signals (those made for handshaking): am I going to find problems communicating with any device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes, that's a problem.  The kind of problem that you can only avoid if you can give specific instructions to the client on how to configure the port on his end.  Which is never not a problem, if that's not done properly then data transfer just won't occur and finding out why can be very awkward.  You are almost guaranteed to get a support call.

A lot of standard programs pay attention to your DTR signal, DSR on their end.  Data Terminal Ready indicates that your device is powered up and whatever the client receives is not produced by electrical noise.  Without DSR they'll just ignore what you send.  Very simple to implement, just tie it to your power supply.

Pretty common is flow control through the RTS/CTS signals.  If enabled in the client program, it won't send you anything until you turn on the Request To Send signal.  Again very simple to implement if you don't need flow control, just tie it logically high like DTR so the client program's configuration doesn't matter.

DCD and Ring are modem signals, pretty unlikely to matter to a generic device.  Tie them logically low.

Very simple to implement, avoids lots of mishaps and support calls, *do* wire them.

And *do* consider whether you can actually live without flow control.  It is very rarely a problem on the client end, modern machines can very easily keep up with the kind of data rates that are common on serial ports.  That is not necessarily the case on your end, the usual limitation is the amount of RAM you can reserve for the receive buffer and the speed of the embedded processor.  A modern machine can firehose you with data pretty easily.  If your uart FIFO or receive interrupt handler or data processing code cannot keep up then the inevitable data loss is very hard to deal with.  Not an issue if you use RTS/CTS or Xon/Xoff handshaking or if you use a master/slave protocol or are comfortable with a low enough baudrate.